# "ionic cordova build" fails to build apk

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I cannot build an apk in cordova. Build always fails.

## Set my android SDK home

export ANDROID_HOME/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/

## First, build cannot find gradle, so i put gradle in path. I have tried this with downloaded gradle or the gradle that i have in android studio.

export PATH=$PATH:/home/felipe/gradle-4.1/bin

## For make sure that i have updated versions of cordova and ionic

npm install -g cordova@latest
npm install -g ionic@latest

## simple sample app

ionic start sidemenu sidemenu --type ionic1

cd sidemenu
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova build android

## And then i got:

```
    > ionic cordova prepare
    > cordova prepare
    ✔ Running command - done!
    Running command: /home/felipe/ionic-testes/sidemenu/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/felipe/ionic-testes/sidemenu
    add to body class: platform-android
    > cordova build android
    ✖ Running command - failed!

    [ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
            You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

    [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):

            Running command: /home/felipe/ionic-testes/sidemenu/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js
            /home/felipe/ionic-testes/sidemenu
            add to body class: platform-android
            ANDROID_HOME=/home/felipe/Android/Sdk/
            JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
            Subproject Path: CordovaLib

            FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

            * What went wrong:
            A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
            > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
            > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
            Required by:
            project :
            > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
            sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested
            target

            * Try:
            Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

            BUILD FAILED

            Total time: 2.176 secs
            Error: /home/felipe/ionic-testes/sidemenu/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error
            output:
            FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

            * What went wrong:
            A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
            > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
            > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
            Required by:
            project :
            > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.2.3/gradle-2.2.3.pom'.
            > sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
            sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested
            target

            * Try:
            Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

## Please. Could somebody help me? Thank you for attention

Answer (score 2):

Solved. I've Just opened in Android Studio.
I don't know why, but the user whose answar was correct has deleted his post. I had installed sdk with sdk manager in Android Studio, and i had installed other updates suggested by Android Studio, but only when i open the project in android studio it did the updates required.

From error message, i guess i have some Certification Authority  missing in my open jdk installation (i am using openjdk from ubuntu repositories and have installed ca-certificates-java package). But, for now, it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Please create project with this commands**

1. Ionic start sidemenu sidemenu --blank
2. Cd sidemenu
3. Add required platform Android, iOS
   4.Cordova build android
4. Cordova run android

Comment: try this one : ionic cordova run android --livereload